# Insert/update data to database from list randomly

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

So I have this db with a table called users. 
In here is column called work, which is currently empty for all users. I've made a list containing many job-titles, and now I want this to be added into the users table under work column.

I figured I'd do something with a array like this:

```
$input = array("worktitle1", "worktitle2", "worktitle3");
$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 1);
```

and then update rand_keys in a simple query:

```
$mysqli->query('UPDATE users SET work = '.$rand_keys.'');
```

However, when I did that, only a number value was inserted and it was the same for all of the xx users I haven in the db.

How can I fix so that it insert a random worktitle for every single row? And not the same worktitle for every users. I thought about doing rand() in the query, but am unsure of this works

BONUS QUESTION: If I want my array_rand to prioritise some worktitles (so in the db a specific worktitle will show 10% more times than others), how can I do that?

Comment: could you add your full code to question?

Comment: 1) add ur snippet to be clear about what you have implemented so far..2) u need custom logic for prioritize..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you have **for** loop or **while** or some array which you want to loop through and insert the dummy data in database table.

I think its because you have used array_rand before the for loop and then using inserting into the database of the random key which you had earlier

Eg:

```
<?php
$input = array("worktitle1", "worktitle2", "worktitle3");

foreach($somearry as $key => $values){
//Now you need to call the array_rand function
$randomKey = array_rand($input, 1); //This will return only the random key of the array

$randomWork = $input[$randomKey]; //This line will give you the random key value of the input array

//Now write your code *here* to insert this random value ie update query
}
```

Using **while** loop as per your request

```
while(some_condition){
//Now you need to call the array_rand function
    $randomKey = array_rand($input, 1); //This will return only the random key of the array

    $randomWork = $input[$randomKey]; //This line will give you the random key value of the input array

    //Now write your code *here* to insert this random value ie update query
}
```

Even you can do the following hard coded way.

> Note : This is just for the sake of demonstration for the user so that
>   he can understand it properly.

```
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
//Now you need to call the array_rand function
    $randomKey = array_rand($input, 1); //This will return only the random key of the array

    $randomWork = $input[$randomKey]; //This line will give you the random key value of the input array

    //Now write your code *here* to insert this random value ie update query

 $mysqli->query("UPDATE users SET work = '$randomWork'");
}
```

Comment: y 1 to 10 not rand(0,n) ??

Comment: Think that your having list of works which is of type array. Even can manipulate the list of array values by looping through it. Which can be achieved by foreach or for loop. To overcome your query I have even included for loop please check. In case any query please revert back

Comment: @RohitS Just wanted to show him by a hard coded way so that he can understand. I dont know by how he wants to put the random way. Since he told that he is getting the same value I thought he might be having some array and want to loop into that and update. So gave that shot

Comment: @chanaveer Hakari  please add it to ur snippet to avoid misinterpretation..also it will also make ur answer more precise to other users

Comment: thanks for answer, currently trying to understand the code you've written. guess my knowledge about arrays isnt as good as i thought

Comment: @KingLove If you  post your full code I may help you out more.

Comment: @KingLove If my answer fulfils your needs or clears your doubts than can you please accept my answer so that others will also get benefited.

Comment: @ChannaveerHakari sorry for late answer! as of right now my full code is your for(i etc. Thats all I have. Including the $input array. Which other code were you thinking that I might have?

Comment: @ChannaveerHakari i am having trouble understand the code, so using some time trying to. the foreach function is not something i've worked with earlier. could you maybe enlighten me on what the values in the foreach() represent?

Comment: @KingLove  Think that your having list of works which is of type array. You can manipulate the list of array values by looping through it. Which can be achieved by foreach or for loop. So once you loop the array with foreach it there will be a pointer which will point to current data. Once it loops, the pointer will increment and starts to point to next value in the array. Thus for every loop the value of the array will increment.

Comment: Oh sorry you meant what loop /while I am using. Thats what I am missing! You see code is fine now @ChannaveerHakari but I am misisng the loop / while. I see! thanks

Comment: Think that you have $numbers = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5); Then size of your array is 5. if you do that by for loop then for($i = 0; $i < count($numbers); $i++){ // This will loop and increment the value of $i for each loop } To put it the same in foreach loop it looks like foreach($numbers as $number){ //$number will be pointing to current value of array and then increment for next loop }

Comment: by now i have enough material do some serious php reading and hopefully make it work. thanks a lot my friend

Comment: @KingLove Even Included while loop code please check

Answer (score 0):

As written, your code selects one title at random and then updates all rows with that title, which is I think what you are saying. You need to loop through all users, select a title, and then set the title "WHERE userid='xxx'" or some other way of selecting specific users.

Weighted randomness. Take you array of titles and add extra entries for the ones you want to weight. If "CEO" is to be 10% more likely to be used, make sure the array has 10 entries of "CEO".